# C++: How to achieve unique ownership but non-unique thread-safe weak access

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, unique-ptr, lifetime, weak-ptr

I have a class `Inner` that should be *uniquely* owned by class `Outer`, specifically, nobody but `Outer` should ever be able to destroy `Inner`, or keep it alive.

However, I want other classes `Consumers`, potentially living on other threads, to be able to reference `Inner` and interact with it fr as long as it lives, and when it eventually dies, these other classes simply know to stop interacting with `Inner`.

In other words, I want unique ownership of `Inner`, but non-unique lifetime-constrained access.

Theoretically, the perfect solution here seems to be:

```
class Inner {
  ...
};

class Outer {
  std::unique_ptr<Inner> unique_inner_;
  std::weak_ptr<Inner> GetWeakInnerForConsumers() {...}
};

class Consumer {
  Consumer(std::weak_ptr<Inner> weak_inner) : weak_inner_(weak_inner) {}

  std::weak_ptr<Inner> weak_inner_;
};
```

But the catch here is that you cannot create a weak pointer from a `std::unique_ptr`, so I'm out of luck.

An alternative is to:

- Have `Inner` inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this<Inner>` *even* though the only instance of `Inner` is owned by a `std::unique_ptr`
- ... and introduce `std::weak_ptr<Inner> GetWeakPtr() {return std::weak_ptr<Inner>(shared_from_this())}`

... however the above doesn't seem to work, since `shared_from_this()` seems to throw an exception when `Inner` is uniquely owned, which is perfectly reasonable. Even if it did work, I think it would probably be susceptible to races, since weak_ptr::lock() couldn't obviously keep a unique_ptr alive.

So given all of this, I can only come up with two solutions:

- Have `Outer` maintain a `std::shared_ptr<Inner>` and just document the heck out of the fact that despite the member, `Outer` is actually the unique owner, and ensure that nobody grabs a strong reference to `Inner`. This seems to be the winning option. Or...
- Instead of the above, hand out raw `Inner*` pointers to all `Consumers`, but have `Consumer` inherit from a `class Inner::Observer`, so `Consumer` can observe the destruction of `Inner`, and maintain some state so that it knows when its raw ptr to `Inner*` is "stale". This seems OK, but is probably susceptible to races between accesses of the raw ptr and the destruction observation

Is the first alternative above my only option? Are there other ways to achieve unique ownership, but non-unique thread-safe weak access?

Comment: Isn't your problem impossible to solve? If one thread has the unfettered right to destroy the object, then another thread may check that the object is alive, start doing stuff with it, but then in the middle of that, the object may die, and you will get UB.

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking too. I guess it would be ideal if, since the weak pointer needs to be thread-safe, it could keep the unique_ptr alive _temporarily_ when it is being used, but that's not a real thing that exists, nor should it... I really just want to prevent handing out long-term strong references to `Inner`, but I'm OK with handing out weak_ptrs that can temporarily keep the underlying object alive throughout the short-term period in which it is used, but I think no such concept exists :)

Comment: As soon as you call `lock` on a `weak_ptr` you request owner ship owner the the object, without requesting ownership you can’t use the object the `weak_prt` is referencing. So at that point `Outer` can’t be an unique owner anymore.

Comment: I know, see my above comment. I think my question is sort of malformed

Comment: `that can temporarily keep the underlying object alive throughout the short-term period` Well that still means that it requests ownership for that sort period of time (to keep it alive). That’s what ownership is about.

Comment: If you a variable (local, member, …) then this variable also expresses unique ownership (like `unique_ptr`) the difference is that the ownership of a `unique_prt` can be transferred to another pointer (`unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` or raw pointer).

Answer (score 1):

As per some discussion with Brian Bi in the comments, I've come to the conclusion that this is actually a problem that is impossible to solve. If you want a weak_ptr to be truly thread-safe, then it must take temporary ownership over the underlying object, in which case it cannot be a weak_ptr of a unique_ptr, obviouly

What I really want is to guarantee that I never hand any strong references out to `Inner` that are stored long-term, so that no other object can *meaningfully* keep `Inner` alive for a period of time. I'm OK with handing out `std::weak_ptr<Inners>`s with the understanding that they will only temporarily keep the underlying `Inner` alive throughout the duration of its access, in which case I'll just have to implement protective measures that:

- Ensure I never hand out a `std::shared_ptr<Inner>` to anyone that is not `Outer`
- Ensure that all consumers of `std::weak_ptr<Inner>` only produce `std::shared_ptr<Inner>`s via `.lock()` and use them temporarily, never storing them "long-term"

In any case, I learned something and took a deep dive into weird ownership problems :)